# Is there an NPC I can hire or create that will do my farming for me?

Tags: the-sims-3

I have a fairly large garden with all types of vegetables. I do have sprinklers, but harvesting gets boring quickly. Will a Butler or a Simbot or some other NPC do my gardening for me?

Comment: Must... resist... inappropriate joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the into the future expansion, you can create a plumbot and give it Gardening Software, which gives it maximum gardening skill and even includes an unlimited amount of the best fertilizer and will prioritize gardening over other actions.

You still have to choose which plants to plant but aside for every week or so when plants die and need to be replaced you won't have to mess with it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem myself- visions of a beautiful healthy garden- just didnt realize I'd be in it from sun rise to sun set. Unfortunately, no, you have to tell one of your controlled sims to do the work.
Sprinklers is a good 1st step, but if it's taking too long still, you might want to narrow your garden down to 1 type of each plant.
Then you can make use of the 'Tend Garden' and 'Fertizile Garden' options; while your sim is still doing the work, one command applies to every plant.
Gardening is serious business in The Sims- if you follow it through, which you are doing now- (good luck with the Omni, I got as far as Steak and Egg plants and rolled another town), one skill can take up all your time in the game

Answer (score 1):

There is a mod called Gardener Service that will use your home phone (not cellphone) and then a gardener (or two if you have bigger garden) will come and take care of it every day. It works with the latest patch but hasn't been uptaded for Seasons so you have to manually cancel the service when the frost kicks in and no gardening can be done. You can find it on modthesims.

Comment: A link to the mod would make this a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your garden is big enough,
1.add a sim as active member of household, then
2.edit his/her traits: green thumb, loves the outdoors, & perfectionist.
3.Make his/her lifetime wish to be a master gardener,
4. put him/her to work. (Tend to garden).

That is what I did. But then again, my farm/garden is on a separate lot & is HUGE, so he never finishes tending all the plants. Just went on vacation to Egypt with my main sims, so we will see if he is still gardening when we get back.. He had been for 24 hrs+ when we left, so fingers crossed...

Hope this helps. I was bummed you couldn't hire gardeners without a mod, but this way is free.

***Makes sure that you use "testingcheatsenabled true" so the needs are static. You will need this cheat activated in order to complete steps 1-3

Answer (score 0):

There is a device called Harvester. It is only found at the consignment shop. It usually runs about $400. It makes harvesting your garden much faster. I have a 9x12 garden and it takes about a sim hour to harvest. Combine that with the sprinklers and it cuts your time way down. You still have to manually weed the garden however. But If your gardening skill is maxed then the weeds don't really affect the quality of your produce.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the premium content from the sim store: SwiftGro Gardening Station, which will enable you to talk, water and fertilize all plants planted within it, at the same time. It occupies 6X6 squares. When bought, you will find it in buy mode, decor, sculptures.

Sim store premium content: Plants Vs. Zombies™ Sunflower, gives sunshine that works perfect as fertilizer (and fun). Buy mode, decor, plants.

Sim store premium content: Grandpa's Grove Tractor, waters, fertilizes, de-weeds and harvests as many plants/trees you have (plant around the tractor track). Free hayrides!

From the Inventors bench (Ambitions EP), you can invent the Harvester, a sort of inverted gun, to harvest many plants at the same time. It makes you tired and dizzy though, I have experienced.

When you get better at gardening, and have fulfilled the requirements listed in that skill window, you won't have as much need to water and weed your plants.

Plantsims (University life EP), are great for garden work!

If you are not opposed to cheating, planting on home lots that are not yours will keep the plants watered and de-weeded automatically, and they can be harvested by you. (Maybe the Life Time Reward: Inappropriate but in a good way, helps). 
I use architect (Ambitions EP), to get access to the lot, and when in buy mode press these keys at the same time: 
Ctrl   Shift    C
then in the grey area that appears, write:

testingcheatsenabled true

then press Enter (the key). Again press keys: ctrl+shift+c, then write:

buydebug on

then press Enter. In the  ?  (question mark), choose plants from the seed section. You cannot plant in any other lot than your home lot without cheats.

It is best to de-activate the cheat codes when you are done:
press ctrl+shift+c, write:

buydebug off

then press Enter. Again press ctrl+shift+c, write:

testingcheatsenabled false

then press Enter. Done! Or you could just choose to play that other household, plant, and then switch back to 'steal' the harvest :)

Plants in communal lots also stay watered and de-weeded and only need harvesting. Access through Edit Town and choose build on lot, and if needed repeat the above steps.

In my experience the computer cannot handle too many plants until the game starts to lag though and I think cheats eventually corrupts the save.

Happy gardening!